# Fetch files with specific extensions using iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, box-api

I wanted to fetch specific files in folder items API. Right now I am getting all the files and I have to filter it myself.

https://box-content.readme.io/reference#get-a-folders-items

Search API https://box-content.readme.io/reference#searching-for-content 
If I want to search all files with specific extensions. I tried searching query as empty string and its returning me error

```
Error Domain=com.box.contentsdk.errordomain Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.box.contentsdk.errordomain error 400.)" UserInfo=0x7ff34a59f7b0 {com.box.contentsdk.jsonerrorresponse=<CFBasicHash 0x7ff34c46b270 [0x10ed8b180]>{type = immutable dict, count = 7,
entries =>
0 : <CFString 0x7ff34c4b3ef0 [0x10ed8b180]>{contents = "status"} = <CFNumber 0xb000000000001903 [0x10ed8b180]>{value = +400, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}
1 : <CFString 0x7ff34c4c1550 [0x10ed8b180]>{contents = "help_url"} = <CFString 0x7ff34c4760d0 [0x10ed8b180]>{contents = "http://developers.box.com/docs/#errors"}
4 : <CFString 0x7ff34c47d2e0 [0x10ed8b180]>{contents = "code"} = <CFString 0x7ff34c4cbaf0 [0x10ed8b180]>{contents = "bad_request"}
5 : <CFString 0x7ff34c48d6a0 [0x10ed8b180]>{contents = "request_id"} = <CFString 0x7ff34c445920 [0x10ed8b180]>{contents = "130336355b6746254f8f"}
6 : <CFString 0x7ff34c4cb960 [0x10ed8b180]>{contents = "context_info"} = <CFBasicHash 0x7ff34c4bc5b0 [0x10ed8b180]>{type = immutable dict, count = 1,
entries =>
1 : <CFString 0x7ff34c43f560 [0x10ed8b180]>{contents = "errors"} = <CFArray 0x7ff34c4bb1e0 [0x10ed8b180]>{type = immutable, count = 1, values = (
0 : <CFBasicHash 0x7ff34c46a510 [0x10ed8b180]>{type = immutable dict, count = 3,
entries =>
0 : <CFString 0x7ff34c476ff0 [0x10ed8b180]>{contents = "name"} = <CFString 0x7ff34c4bc380 [0x10ed8b180]>{contents = "to_search"}
1 : <CFString 0x7ff34c4bc3a0 [0x10ed8b180]>{contents = "message"} = <CFString 0x7ff34c4bcc60 [0x10ed8b180]>{contents = "Invalid value ''."}
2 : <CFString 0x7ff34c476fd0 [0x10ed8b180]>{contents = "reason"} = <CFString 0x7ff34c4b8500 [0x10ed8b180]>{contents = "invalid_parameter"}
}

)}
}

7 : <CFString 0x7ff34c4bc3a0 [0x10ed8b180]>{contents = "message"} = <CFString 0x7ff34c476100 [0x10ed8b180]>{contents = "Bad Request"}
9 : <CFString 0x7ff34a52b970 [0x10ed8b180]>{contents = "type"} = <CFString 0x7ff34a595d80 [0x10ed8b180]>{contents = "error"}
}
}
```

Please let me know how to all the files of specific types.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get all files in box account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107389/get-all-files-in-box-account)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting some of my observations while working on **BOX-APIs**.

First of all there is no way to fetch all the files_list in 1 go for BOX service, as few users can have millions and millions of files. So, to fetch files which belong to few specific type *(like only .jpg/.png)* in one go will be time taking as I can think of server side implementation which has to go through all the files list for the user to search for that given type.

But there is a way using Search API to fetch for files having some file extension.

```
//Sample example

BOXContentClient *contentClient = [BOXContentClient defaultClient];
NSString *searchQuery = <query - text>;
NSArray *fileExtensions = <array of extensions required>;
BOXSearchRequest *searchRequest = [contentClient searchRequestWithQuery:searchQuery 
                                                                inRange:NSMakeRange(0, 9999)]; // max of 10000 files for
searchRequest.requestAllItemFields = YES; // will fetch all the fields for the files
searchRequest.fileExtensions = fileExtensions; // set the extensions for the files needed
searchRequest.type = @"file"; // searching for files , can be extended for folders
searchRequest.contentTypes = @[@"name"]; // Search in Names only , it can search in file content also incase of text related files (.txt, .doc)
[searchRequest performRequestWithCompletion:^(NSArray *items, NSUInteger totalCount, NSRange range, NSError *error) {
 // Do what ever you want
}];
```

One more good answer referred by @JohnHoerr [Get all files in box account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107389/get-all-files-in-box-account)

Hope this helps for anyone looking for this :)

Answer (score 1):

How about using the extension itself as the query e.g.

curl -X GET https://api.box.com/2.0/search?query=.jpg -H "Authorization: Bearer "

And then you can use other query parameter options like ancestor folder id for restricting it.

Comment: your solution work when we want only one type of file. If I want .jpg and .png files then what should we do? Their documentation says "query: The string to search for; can be matched against item names, descriptions, text content of a file, and other fields of the different item types." So that means it will be overhead for server also string matching through all the files and returning, response will be slower as well